# Parse IOS for loop sum total

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to run a for loop and adding all the objects in the parse database to come up with a total. This is the error I keep getting:  Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSNumber *' and 'NSNumber *')

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSNumber *sum;
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSString *balanceString = object[@"startingBalance"];

        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber *balanceNumber = [f numberFromString:balanceString];

        sum = sum + balanceNumber;
        NSLog(@"%f", sum);
    }


}];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert `NSNumber` to primitive type (e.g. `float` or `int`) in order to perform arithmetic operation

```
float sum = 0;
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; // and you should reuse formatter
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
    NSString *balanceString = object[@"startingBalance"];
    NSNumber *balanceNumber = [f numberFromString:balanceString];

    sum += [balanceNumber floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform arithmetic operation on  two **nsnumber** objects, you should convert those objects into float, long, double. After performing arithmetic operation, you can convert into **nsnumber** type.